# Why does the technique to find derivative of $y=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{a'x^2+b'x+c'}$ quickly, works?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I just watched a video about a very good technique to evaluate derivative of $ y=\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{a'x^2+b'x+c'} ,\quad a'\neq0$ quickly:

$$\large y'=\large\dfrac{{ \begin{vmatrix}{a} && {b} \\ {a'} && {b'}\end{vmatrix} }x^2+\color{red}2{ \begin{vmatrix}{a} && {c} \\ {a'} && {c'}\end{vmatrix} }x+{ \begin{vmatrix}{b} && {c} \\ {b'} && {c'}\end{vmatrix} }}{(a'x^2+b'x+c')^2}$$

I wonder is it possible to prove this is true? Of course we can calculate derivative of $y$ and expanding the terms and compare it with the formula that I mentioned. But is it possible to check this is true intuitively Or without expanding? ( it is obvious that denominator should be $(a'x^2+b'x+c')^2$  )

Comment: Hint: eliminate the denominator, differentiate, then solve for $y'$ as a linear system and use the multilinearity of determinants to get that particular expression.

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\,y \, (a'x^2+b'x+c') & &= ax^2+bx+c
\\ \,y \, (2a'x+b') &+ \,y'\,(a'x^2+b'x+c') &= 2ax+b
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What you are trying to show is that $(a'x^2+b'x+c') (2ax + b) - (ax^2+bx+c) (2a'x + b')$ can be rearranged to be written as ${ \begin{vmatrix}{a} && {b} \\ {a'} && {b'}\end{vmatrix} }x^2 + ...$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=a'x^2+b'x+c'$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d(f/g)}{dx}
&=\frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{g^2}\left|\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ 0&f'&f\\ 0&g'&g\end{matrix}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{g^2}\left|\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ a&f'&f\\ a'&g'&g\end{matrix}\right|\quad(R_2=R_2+aR_1;\ R_3=R_3+a'R_1)\\
&=\frac{1}{g^2}\left|\begin{matrix}1&-2x&0\\ a&b&f\\ a'&b'&g\end{matrix}\right|\quad(C_2=C_2-2xC_1)\\
&=\frac{1}{g^2}\left|\begin{matrix}1&-2x&x^2\\ a&b&c\\ a'&b'&c'\end{matrix}\right|\quad(C_3=C_3-x^2C_1-xC_2)\\
&=\frac{1}{g^2}\left(\left|\begin{matrix}b&c\\ b'&c'\end{matrix}\right|+2x\left|\begin{matrix}a&c\\ a'&c'\end{matrix}\right|+x^2\left|\begin{matrix}a&b\\ a'&b'\end{matrix}\right|\right).
\end{aligned}